# How to share home directory in FTP

Tags: linux, debian, fedora, ftp, vsftpd

I installed an FTP server on Linux Debian and fedora computers but when I trying to access to the FTP server with the Local area network it shows me the wrong directory. How to change the configurations of the FTP server? How can I share > /home/ dir on FTP?

Comment: "How to change configuration"... by editing the config file? `/etc/vsftpd.conf`

Comment: Also make sure you set the appropriate SELinux Boolean on Fedora.